# Can someone help me to display my filter search correctly and also i'm unable to find my error?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, filter

//this is my productContent1.php file,i want to display product filter search options to allow users to search product with filter.I included class Product.php and then call methods to display filter options values from MySQL database table vehicle

```
<div class="products">
<?php
include 'class/Product.php';
$product = new Product();   
?>  
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                      <form class="form-inline" action=action.php" method="POST">
                 
                        <label>Type:</label>
                        <select name="Type" id="type" required>
                          <?php
                          $type = $product->gettype();
                          foreach($Type as $typeDetails){   
                          ?>
                            <optgroup label="Type" value="<?php echo $typeDetails["type"]; ?>"  >          <?php echo $typeDetails["type"]; ?>
                                <option value="">-- All --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Motorcycles --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Mini-Trucks --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Vans --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Cars --</option>
                        </select>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        <label>Make:</label>
                        <select name="Make" id="make" required>
                          <?php
                          $make = $product->getmake();
                          foreach($Make as $makeDetails){   
                          ?>
                            <optgroup label="Make" value="<?php echo $makeDetails["make"]; ?>"  > <?php echo $makeDetails["make"]; ?>
                                <option value="">-- All --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Suzuki --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Honda --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Yamaha --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Toyota --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Nissan --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Mitsubishi --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Mazda --</option>
                        </select>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        <label>Price:</label>
                        <select name="Price" id="price" required>
                          <?php
                          $price = $product->getprice();
                          foreach($price as $priceDetails){ 
                          ?>
                            <optgroup label="Price" value="<?php echo $priceDetails["price"]; ?>"  > <?php echo $priceDetails["price"]; ?>
                                <option value="">-- All --</option>
                                <option value="">-- 0-10000 --</option>
                                <option value="">-- 10000-50000 --</option>
                                <option value="">-- 50000-500000 --</option>
                                <option value="">-- >500000 --</option>
                        </select>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>

                        <label> Size:</label>
                        <select name="Size" id="size" required>
                          <?php
                          $size = $product->getsize();
                          foreach($size as $sizeDetails){   
                          ?>
                            <optgroup label="Size" value="<?php echo $sizeDetails["size"]; ?>"  > <?php echo $sizeDetails["size"]; ?>
                                <option value="">-- All --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Small --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Medium --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Large --</option>
                        </select>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                 
                        <label> Color:</label>
                        <select name="Color" id="color" required>
                          <?php
                           $color = $product->getcolor();
                          foreach($color as $ColorDetails){ 
                          ?>
                            <optgroup label="Color" value="<?php echo $colorDetails["color"]; ?>"  > <?php echo $colorDetails["color"]; ?>
                                <option value="">-- All --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Red --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Blue --</option>
                                <option value="">-- White --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Black --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Grey --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Silver --</option>
                                <option value="">-- Orange --</option>
                        </select>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <button type="submit" class="filled-button btn-block">Search</button>
                        </form>
<div class="col md-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="Toyota-Allion-Details.html"><img src="images/Toyota allion.jpg"     alt="Toyota Allion"></a>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <div class="card-title"><h3>Toyota Allion</h3></div>
                                    <div class="card-price"><h3>Rs 850 000</h3></div>
                                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Available in white only</small></p>
                                    <small>
                                        <strong title="Author"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>53 000km</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <strong title="Author"><i class="fa fa-cube"></i>1600cc</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <strong title="Views"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Automatic</strong>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <a href="Toyota-Axio-Details.html"><img src="images/Toyota axio.jpg" alt="Toyota Axio"></a>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <div class="card-title"><h3>Toyota Axio</h3></div>
                                    <div class="card-price"><h3>Rs 750 000</h3></div>
                                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Available in white only</small></p>
                                    <small>
                                        <strong title="Author"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>25 453km</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <strong title="Author"><i class="fa fa-cube"></i>1500cc</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <strong title="Views"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Automatic</strong>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
    
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="pages">
                            <li class="active"><a href="productContent1.html">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="productContent2.html">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="productContent3.html">3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="productContent2.html" class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

//in action.phpI included class Product.php and call method $product->searchProducts() to get search result HTML and passed as JSON response using json_encode.

```
<?php
include 'class/Product.php';
$product = new Product();
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
$html = $product->searchProducts($_POST);
$data = array(
    "html"  => $html,   
);
echo json_encode($data);    
}
?>
```

//Product.php to define method searchProducts(), to get product filter search data from MySQL database table.I created SELECT query with filter search options and get data. Then create result HTML with result data and return as complete search result HTML.

```
<?php
function searchProducts(){
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->productTable;
if(isset($_POST["type"])) {
    $typeFilterData = implode("','", $_POST["type"]);
    $sqlQuery .= "
    AND type IN('".$typeFilterData."')";
}
if(isset($_POST["make"])){
    $makeFilterData = implode("','", $_POST["make"]);
    $sqlQuery .= "
    AND make IN('".$makeFilterData."')";
}
if(isset($_POST["price"])) {
    $priceFilterData = implode("','", $_POST["price"]);
    $sqlQuery .= "
    AND price IN('".$priceFilterData."')";
}
if(isset($_POST["size"])) {
    $sizeFilterData = implode("','", $_POST["size"]);
    $sqlQuery .= "
    AND size IN('".$sizeFilterData."')";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["color"])) {
    $colorFilterData = implode("','", $_POST["color"]);
    $sqlQuery .= "
    AND color IN('".$colorFilterData."')";
 }
 $sqlQuery .= " ORDER By price";
 $result = mysqli_query($this->dbConnect, $sqlQuery);
 $totalResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $searchResultHTML = '';
 if($totalResult > 0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $searchResultHTML .= '';
    }
 }
 else {
    $searchResultHTML = '<h3>No product found.</h3>';
  }
    return $searchResultHTML;   
 }
?>
```

//search.js to define a function filterSearch() to make Ajax request according to filter search option display search result. The Ajax request made to action.php to load search data from MySQL database table as JSON response.

```
function filterSearch() {
$('.searchResult').html('<div id="loading">Loading .....</div>');
var action = 'fetch_data';
var type = getFilterData('type');
var make = getFilterData('make');
var price = getFilterData('price');
var size = getFilterData('size');
var color = getFilterData('color');
$.ajax({
    url:"action.php",
    method:"POST",
    dataType: "json",       
    data:{action:action, type:type, make:make, price:price, size:size, color:color},
    success:function(data){
        $('.searchResult').html(data.html);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Hi, what does work ? are you getting any error ?

Comment: Warning: include(class/Product.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\productContent1.php on line 45

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'class/Product.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\productContent1.php on line 45

@swati the error i'm getting...Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Product' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\productContent1.php:46 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\productContent1.php on line 46

Comment: Error simply say that class at path which you have specify doesn't exist or its wrong.